# Why are my fed TensorFlow Placeholder values being replaced with calculated ones?

Tags: logging, machine-learning, tensorflow

I've defined some calculated values and associated summaries using

```
keep_prob_val = tf.sub(1.0, tf.train.exponential_decay(1 - FLAGS.keep_prob, global_step, FLAGS.decay_steps,                                                        FLAGS.dropout_decay_rate, staircase=False))
keep_prob_summary = tf.scalar_summary('params/keep_prob', keep_prob_val)
```

and set up some merged summaries with

```
train_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(FLAGS.train_dir.format(log_id), tf.get_default_graph())
test_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(test_dir)
merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()
```

But when I subsequently

```
sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: xs, y_: ys,
                                keep_prob: sess.run(keep_prob_val)})
# ...
test_writer.add_summary(sess.run(merged, feed_dict={ ..., keep_prob: some_val}), 
                        global_step=gs)
```

where `keep_prob` has previously been defined as

```
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob')
```

the summary information I get is the calculated `keep_prob_val` and not the `some_val` I've fed. This happens even though — as expected — if I omit explicitly feeding `keep_prob`, I get an error.

As near as I can tell, this is happening only for summaries involving keep_prob. When I, for example

```
sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={ ..., keep_prob: some_val})
```

I seem to get an `accuracy` calculated using `some_val`, and this corresponds to the associated summary.

Why is my fed value for `keep_prob` being ignored in my summary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summary does not depend on your `keep_prob` placeholder, but instead on a `FLAGS.keep_prob` value:

```
keep_prob_val = tf.sub(1.0, tf.train.exponential_decay(
    1 - FLAGS.keep_prob, global_step, FLAGS.decay_steps,                
    FLAGS.dropout_decay_rate, staircase=False))

keep_prob_summary = tf.scalar_summary('params/keep_prob', keep_prob_val)
```

Therefore, your summary will always contain the (possibly decayed) value that was set by the `--keep_prob` flag (or its default value).

To make the summary reflect the fed value, you should simply redefine `keep_prob_val` and `keep_prob_summary` to depend on the placeholder:

```
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob')

# ...

keep_prob_val = tf.sub(1.0, tf.train.exponential_decay(
    1 - keep_prob,  # N.B. Critical change goes here!
    global_step, FLAGS.decay_steps, FLAGS.dropout_decay_rate, staircase=False))

keep_prob_summary = tf.scalar_summary('params/keep_prob', keep_prob_val)
```

Comment: Wow, what a dumb error! (Is there an idiom or style guideline for naming `tf.Tensor` vs `tf.Placeholder` vs regular python variables. This is the second time I've been caught by something like this, and clearly marking things as one or the other would be helpful, but I don't want to make up something random.)